# Is this a Monad implementation?

Tags: scala, monads

I wrote a simple `Scala` code which is a `Monad` implementation, in my opinion.

Here is a base trait:

```
trait M[A] {

  def unit(x: A): M[A]

  def bind[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]

}
```

Implementation:

```
case class Monad(e: String) extends M[String] {    

  def unit(x: String): M[String] = {
    Monad(x)
  }

  def bind[B](f: (String) => M[B]): M[B] = {
    f(e)
  }    

}
```

Could anyone confirm if it is a true Monad implementation or not?

Comment: I don't think so, but I can't put my finger on why.

Comment: Looks like the identity monad, but restricted to strings for some reason.

Comment: @Bergi and what about `trait`? is it ok?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a monad since it has the wrong kind. Your monad trait should be defined for a type constructor with a single type argument e.g.

```
trait Monad[M[_]] {
    def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
    def bind[A, B](ma: M[A], bf: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

Note the methods `unit` and `bind` are generic in the 'value' types `A` and `B`.

then your implementations should be for a particular type constructor (e.g. Option, List), for example

```
implicit object ObjectMonad extends Monad[Option] {
    def unit[A](a: A) = Some(a)
    def bind[A, B](oa: Option[A], bf: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = {
        oa match {
            case Some(a) => bf(a)
            case None => None
        }
    }
}
```